# Jenkins Role Strategy - Assign Role

Tags: jenkins

After latest update of 'role based strategy' plugin, I can't assign roles anymore, and I cant see assigned roles.

I'm getting ERROR instead of username, and when I if I click on save, I'm getting:

> HTTP ERROR 403 Problem accessing /role-strategy/assignSubmit. Reason:
>       No valid crumb was included in the request

This happened before, and I rolled back plugin to earlier version, and all worked file. But right now, i do not have roll back button near that plugin. I should not keep Jenkins up to date.

Comment: Are you using the github auth plugin? I faced this same issue and the problem was the github oauth plugin version 0.32. When I rolled back to v0.31 it was working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

So ok, the problem is actually in GitHub Authentication plugin. Downgrade it to previous version, and everything will work. Hopefully in next version they will fix the problem...